# Make responsive button in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make button in react native with dynamic width. I just want to supply text in button component it create button according to text width.

Answer (score 2):

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor:'red', paddingTop:10, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, paddingBottom:10}}>
        <Text style={{color:'white', fontWeight:'bold'}}>BUTTON 2</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, use padding. I've set up an example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/Hwinnw).

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor:'red', paddingTop:10, paddingLeft:20, paddingRight:20, paddingBottom:10}}>
    <Text style={{color:'white', fontWeight:'bold'}}>BUTTON 2</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

https://rnplay.org/apps/Hwinnw